# if I rotate the cylinder in x, then y and then z in different theta. What will be the height in y axis for the final cylinder?

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

I was new to three.js and in three.js when I created a cylinder it will be parallel to y axis by default, give the height in y axis as value a.

And then if I rotate the cylinder in x, then y and then z in different theta. What will be the height in y axis for the final cylinder (like the code below)?

I tried but cannot find the answer.
Thanks very much for any answers.    :)

```
cylinder.rotation.x = theta1;
cylinder.rotation.y = theta2;
cylinder.rotation.z = theta3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask this question on mathematics stack exchange, or you could execute the following code (plug in your X, Y, and Z values). So in this example, our cylinder is 1.0 height along the positive y axis:

```
var x = 0.0;
var y = 1.0;
var z = 0.0;

var e = new THREE.Euler(theta1, theta2, theta3);
var p = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
p.applyEuler(e);

console.log(e);
```